# Windows Azure application crashes IISConfigurator.exe

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, iis-express

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012, and Windows Azure SDK for .NET v11.0.5022, which installs IIS Express 8. When I attempt to run a Windows Azure app, IISConfigurator.exe will crash

[image]

This is the log file

```
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00011404:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:18:56.304] Started 

iisconfigurator with args /start
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00011404:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:18:56.32] StartForeground selected. Check if an instance is already running
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00011404:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:18:56.341] Starting service WAS
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00011404:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:18:56.51] Starting service w3svc
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00011404:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:18:56.516] Starting service apphostsvc
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00011404:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:18:56.583] Unhandled exception: IsTerminating 'True', Message 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.ConfigureAnonymousAuthentication(String configPath)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(Boolean setupRewrite, String configPath)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(Boolean setupRewrite, String configPath)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.IISConfigurator.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.WCFServiceHost.Open()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.StartForgroundProcess()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.DoActions(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.Main(String[] args)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
'
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00010228:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:19:07.934] Started iisconfigurator with args /start
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00010228:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:19:07.941] StartForeground selected. Check if an instance is already running
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00010228:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:19:07.963] Starting service WAS
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00010228:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:19:08.032] Starting service w3svc
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00010228:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:19:08.037] Starting service apphostsvc
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00010228:00000001, 2012/07/17 19:19:08.106] Unhandled exception: IsTerminating 'True', Message 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.ConfigureAnonymousAuthentication(String configPath)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(Boolean setupRewrite, String configPath)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(Boolean setupRewrite, String configPath)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.IISConfigurator.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.WCFServiceHost.Open()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.StartForgroundProcess()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.DoActions(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.Main(String[] args)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
'
```

It seems the application is trying to bind to IIS version 7.0 where IIS version 7.9.0.0 (IIS 8 Release Candidate) is installed.

Any way I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, installed "IIS Management Console" using MS Web Platform Installer and it solved the issue.

This was happening because IISConfigurator.exe is trying to use a reference to "Microsoft.Web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0..." which I didn't had before installing the management console.

Comment: This saved me hours of trouble shooting...life saver. THANKS!

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks! I used Control Panel > Add/Remove Windows Features to install "IIS Management Console" and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If IIS Express doesn’t work, you can always use full IIS. In the properties page of the Windows Azure project, click the Web tab, and you can choose to use full IIS.

From the screenshot, it looks like you’re on Windows 7 (as your window has round corners). Please note Windows 7 only stands by full IIS 7. Please also make sure you’ve enabled full IIS in Windows features. If you want to use full IIS 8, it is needed to use Windows 8 or Windows Server 8.

Comment: Thanks, Ming Xu. I want to stick with something simple and avoid the hassle of administrating IISExpress. Also, I want to be able to follow the Azure examples exactly, so I can rule out what is the causes when the building process fails.

Comment: Then please try to reinstall Windows Azure SDK and IIS Express to see whether it helps.

Comment: The problem magically disappeared after I installed IIS Management Console and IIS HWC. See http://goo.gl/K3ZAJ for details

I would love to get to the bottom of the error, because I see a lot of similar posts on the Internet. Hopefully this error can be avoided for the others too